# RSA signature generated with mbedtls, can't verify with C# (bouncycastle) application

Tags: c#, c, rsa, bouncycastle, mbedtls

I'm signing a 32 byte challenge with RSA, using mbedtls.

The relevant lines of C code look like this; I'm creating a signature in 'signature' for the 32 byte 'challenge' array, using a private key:

```
mbedtls_rsa_context rsa;

mbedtls_rsa_init(&rsa, MBEDTLS_RSA_PKCS_V21, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256);

mbedtls_rsa_rsassa_pss_sign(&rsa, f_rng, &prng, MBEDTLS_RSA_PRIVATE, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256, 32, challenge, signature)
```

This works, I can verify the signature with mbedtls. 'rsa' is another instance, thisone using the public key:

```
mbedtls_rsa_rsassa_pss_verify(&rsa, NULL, NULL, MBEDTLS_RSA_PUBLIC, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256, sizeof(challenge), challenge, signature);
```

So far, so good. What I cannot get to work is verifying this signature in a C# application. I started out with the RSACryptoServiceProvider class, couldn't get that to work. Eventually found out about the bouncycastle stuff. Looks better than the RSACryptoServiceProvider , but I can't get that to work either.

I'm loading the public key, challenge and signature as used in the mbedtls stuff.

```
RsaKeyParameters key = new RsaKeyParameters(false, new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(Nstring, 16), new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(Estring, 16));

ISigner sig = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256WITHRSA/PSS");

sig.Init(false, key);

sig.BlockUpdate(challenge, 0, challenge.Length);
Console.WriteLine("result: " + sig.VerifySignature(signature));
```

VerifySignature fails ("result: false").... :(

I think I have the data in the correct format. This is the public key exponent and modulus on the C side:

```
unsigned char E[] = { 0x01,0x00,0x01 };
unsigned char N[] = { 0xC2,0x7E,0xC0,0xCD,0x1B,0xEA,0xE1,0x2E,0x5F,0x15,0xE3,0x9A,0xA3,0x5C,0xF2,0x0A,0xB5,0xAE,0x7F,0x22,0xE0,0x8A,0xA8,0xA7,0x44,0x8E,0xDD,0x1F,0x3C,0xDD,0xDA,0xE5,0xBB,0x23,0x8F,0xF2,0xED,0xFA,0xDF,0xC4,0x95,0x72,0x67,0x00,0x49,0xCF,0xCD,0xE7,0x35,0x56,0x49,0xE7,0x16,0xCC,0x5A,0x9A,0x37,0xFA,0x0C,0x6B,0x79,0xA5,0x5B,0x5A,0x4C,0x1F,0x48,0xE7,0x62,0x59,0xFD,0x60,0x4A,0xCC,0xFF,0xB6,0x62,0xD2,0xEB,0x41,0xF3,0xB1,0xDA,0x2F,0x61,0x55,0x68,0xD1,0x77,0x7C,0x16,0xCA,0x62,0x2F,0xF9,0x6D,0x03,0xED,0xCF,0x89,0x9D,0x1E,0x5B,0xA8,0x4D,0x90,0xDF,0x80,0x1B,0x75,0xE0,0x6D,0xAA,0x0D,0x8A,0xCC,0xA1,0x5B,0xE5,0xD8,0xA0,0x97,0xFF,0x75,0x4B,0xDA,0x39,0x7D };
```

This is how I use them on the C# side:

```
Estring = "010001";
Nstring = "C27EC0CD1BEAE12E5F15E39AA35CF20AB5AE7F22E08AA8A7448EDD1F3CDDDAE5BB238FF2EDFADFC49572670049CFCDE7355649E716CC5A9A37FA0C6B79A55B5A4C1F48E76259FD604ACCFFB662D2EB41F3B1DA2F615568D1777C16CA622FF96D03EDCF899D1E5BA84D90DF801B75E06DAA0D8ACCA15BE5D8A097FF754BDA397D";
```

'challenge' and 'signature' are 8 bit (unsigned char/byte) array's on both sides, containing the same data.

--edit (adding some actual challenge/signature values)--

```
unsigned char challenge[32] = {
0x1E,0x36,0x44,0x82,0x2A,0x60,0x79,0xDE,0x7D,0x49,0x92,0xAA,0x5E,0x25,0xB5,0x80,0x6D,0x95,0x7E,0xE9,0x3A,0x30,0x9B,0x7F,0x82,0x4B,0xB0,0x26,0x3D,0x00,0x0C,0x2E
};

unsigned char signature[128] = {
0xA7,0x64,0x07,0xD0,0x06,0x35,0x0E,0x3F,0x6C,0xFB,0xA1,0xB8,0xDC,0xC5,0x68,0x97,0x65,0xD5,0x7A,0x74,0xFC,0x96,0x01,0x53,0xE0,0x16,0xBC,0xCA,0x59,0x40,0x37,0xC8,0xC9,0x89,0xC2,0x84,0x2A,0xC6,0x51,0xCD,0xDA,0x29,0x65,0xBF,0x39,0x68,0x1E,0x3A,0x0E,0x4E,0x81,0x2E,0xBC,0x08,0x41,0x6A,0xC8,0x95,0xD1,0x43,0x35,0x7C,0x14,0xF6,0x2D,0xE8,0xDA,0x94,0x6C,0x80,0x9D,0x86,0x19,0x4B,0x16,0xD3,0x17,0xAB,0x0E,0x7F,0xE8,0x5F,0xC9,0xB5,0xCC,0x9B,0x96,0xE6,0xAB,0xB6,0x7B,0x11,0x5B,0xC8,0x01,0xD7,0x16,0x50,0xD3,0xF8,0xB4,0xF5,0xCB,0xC2,0xC4,0x70,0xCD,0x84,0x50,0xD0,0x7F,0xA9,0xC3,0x8F,0xE1,0x6B,0x54,0xF4,0x32,0xB8,0x6E,0xCD,0xD2,0xCF,0x78,0x98,0x69,0x7F
};
```

What am I missing here?

--edit (adding some copy/paste ready code)--

mbedtls/c++ project, works (output "Verification success")

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mbedtls/config.h"
#include "mbedtls/platform.h"
#include "mbedtls/error.h"
#include "mbedtls/rsa.h"
#include "mbedtls/error.h"
#include "mbedtls/bignum.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int ret;
    char errbuf[100];
    mbedtls_rsa_context ctx;

    /* Key */
    unsigned char E[] = { 0x01,0x00,0x01 };
    unsigned char N[] = { 0xC2,0x7E,0xC0,0xCD,0x1B,0xEA,0xE1,0x2E,0x5F,0x15,0xE3,0x9A,0xA3,0x5C,0xF2,0x0A,0xB5,0xAE,0x7F,0x22,0xE0,0x8A,0xA8,0xA7,0x44,0x8E,0xDD,0x1F,0x3C,0xDD,0xDA,0xE5,0xBB,0x23,0x8F,0xF2,0xED,0xFA,0xDF,0xC4,0x95,0x72,0x67,0x00,0x49,0xCF,0xCD,0xE7,0x35,0x56,0x49,0xE7,0x16,0xCC,0x5A,0x9A,0x37,0xFA,0x0C,0x6B,0x79,0xA5,0x5B,0x5A,0x4C,0x1F,0x48,0xE7,0x62,0x59,0xFD,0x60,0x4A,0xCC,0xFF,0xB6,0x62,0xD2,0xEB,0x41,0xF3,0xB1,0xDA,0x2F,0x61,0x55,0x68,0xD1,0x77,0x7C,0x16,0xCA,0x62,0x2F,0xF9,0x6D,0x03,0xED,0xCF,0x89,0x9D,0x1E,0x5B,0xA8,0x4D,0x90,0xDF,0x80,0x1B,0x75,0xE0,0x6D,0xAA,0x0D,0x8A,0xCC,0xA1,0x5B,0xE5,0xD8,0xA0,0x97,0xFF,0x75,0x4B,0xDA,0x39,0x7D };

    /* Challenge */
    unsigned char challenge[] = {
        0x1E,0x36,0x44,0x82,0x2A,0x60,0x79,0xDE,0x7D,0x49,0x92,0xAA,0x5E,0x25,0xB5,0x80,0x6D,0x95,0x7E,0xE9,0x3A,0x30,0x9B,0x7F,0x82,0x4B,0xB0,0x26,0x3D,0x00,0x0C,0x2E
    };

    /* Response */
    unsigned char responseGiven[] = {
        0xA7,0x64,0x07,0xD0,0x06,0x35,0x0E,0x3F,0x6C,0xFB,0xA1,0xB8,0xDC,0xC5,0x68,0x97,0x65,0xD5,0x7A,0x74,0xFC,0x96,0x01,0x53,0xE0,0x16,0xBC,0xCA,0x59,0x40,0x37,0xC8,0xC9,0x89,0xC2,0x84,0x2A,0xC6,0x51,0xCD,0xDA,0x29,0x65,0xBF,0x39,0x68,0x1E,0x3A,0x0E,0x4E,0x81,0x2E,0xBC,0x08,0x41,0x6A,0xC8,0x95,0xD1,0x43,0x35,0x7C,0x14,0xF6,0x2D,0xE8,0xDA,0x94,0x6C,0x80,0x9D,0x86,0x19,0x4B,0x16,0xD3,0x17,0xAB,0x0E,0x7F,0xE8,0x5F,0xC9,0xB5,0xCC,0x9B,0x96,0xE6,0xAB,0xB6,0x7B,0x11,0x5B,0xC8,0x01,0xD7,0x16,0x50,0xD3,0xF8,0xB4,0xF5,0xCB,0xC2,0xC4,0x70,0xCD,0x84,0x50,0xD0,0x7F,0xA9,0xC3,0x8F,0xE1,0x6B,0x54,0xF4,0x32,0xB8,0x6E,0xCD,0xD2,0xCF,0x78,0x98,0x69,0x7F
    };

    mbedtls_rsa_init(&ctx, MBEDTLS_RSA_PKCS_V21, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256);

    /* Load public key */
    if ((ret = mbedtls_rsa_import_raw(&ctx, N, sizeof(N), NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, E, sizeof(E))) != 0) {
        mbedtls_strerror(ret, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
        mbedtls_printf("mbedtls_rsa_import_raw failed, returned %d, %s\n\n", ret, errbuf);
        return 0;
    }
    if ((ret = mbedtls_rsa_complete(&ctx)) != 0) {
        mbedtls_strerror(ret, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
        mbedtls_printf("mbedtls_rsa_complete failed, returned %d, %s\n\n", ret, errbuf);
        return 0;
    }

    /* Verify response */
    if ((ret = mbedtls_rsa_rsassa_pss_verify(&ctx, NULL, NULL, MBEDTLS_RSA_PUBLIC, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256, 32, challenge, responseGiven))) {
        mbedtls_strerror(ret, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
        mbedtls_printf("mbedtls_rsa_rsassa_pss_verify failed, returned %d - %s\n\n", ret, errbuf);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        mbedtls_printf("Verification success\n");
    }

    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

Bouncycastle/C# project, fails (output "VerifySignature failed")

```
using System;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests;

namespace cryptotest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* Key */
            byte[] E = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 };
            byte[] N = new byte[] { 0xC2, 0x7E, 0xC0, 0xCD, 0x1B, 0xEA, 0xE1, 0x2E, 0x5F, 0x15, 0xE3, 0x9A, 0xA3, 0x5C, 0xF2, 0x0A, 0xB5, 0xAE, 0x7F, 0x22, 0xE0, 0x8A, 0xA8, 0xA7, 0x44, 0x8E, 0xDD, 0x1F, 0x3C, 0xDD, 0xDA, 0xE5, 0xBB, 0x23, 0x8F, 0xF2, 0xED, 0xFA, 0xDF, 0xC4, 0x95, 0x72, 0x67, 0x00, 0x49, 0xCF, 0xCD, 0xE7, 0x35, 0x56, 0x49, 0xE7, 0x16, 0xCC, 0x5A, 0x9A, 0x37, 0xFA, 0x0C, 0x6B, 0x79, 0xA5, 0x5B, 0x5A, 0x4C, 0x1F, 0x48, 0xE7, 0x62, 0x59, 0xFD, 0x60, 0x4A, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xB6, 0x62, 0xD2, 0xEB, 0x41, 0xF3, 0xB1, 0xDA, 0x2F, 0x61, 0x55, 0x68, 0xD1, 0x77, 0x7C, 0x16, 0xCA, 0x62, 0x2F, 0xF9, 0x6D, 0x03, 0xED, 0xCF, 0x89, 0x9D, 0x1E, 0x5B, 0xA8, 0x4D, 0x90, 0xDF, 0x80, 0x1B, 0x75, 0xE0, 0x6D, 0xAA, 0x0D, 0x8A, 0xCC, 0xA1, 0x5B, 0xE5, 0xD8, 0xA0, 0x97, 0xFF, 0x75, 0x4B, 0xDA, 0x39, 0x7D };

            /* Challenge */
            byte[] challenge = new byte[] {
                0x1E,0x36,0x44,0x82,0x2A,0x60,0x79,0xDE,0x7D,0x49,0x92,0xAA,0x5E,0x25,0xB5,0x80,0x6D,0x95,0x7E,0xE9,0x3A,0x30,0x9B,0x7F,0x82,0x4B,0xB0,0x26,0x3D,0x00,0x0C,0x2E
            };

            /* Response */
            byte[] responseGiven = new byte[]{
                0xA7,0x64,0x07,0xD0,0x06,0x35,0x0E,0x3F,0x6C,0xFB,0xA1,0xB8,0xDC,0xC5,0x68,0x97,0x65,0xD5,0x7A,0x74,0xFC,0x96,0x01,0x53,0xE0,0x16,0xBC,0xCA,0x59,0x40,0x37,0xC8,0xC9,0x89,0xC2,0x84,0x2A,0xC6,0x51,0xCD,0xDA,0x29,0x65,0xBF,0x39,0x68,0x1E,0x3A,0x0E,0x4E,0x81,0x2E,0xBC,0x08,0x41,0x6A,0xC8,0x95,0xD1,0x43,0x35,0x7C,0x14,0xF6,0x2D,0xE8,0xDA,0x94,0x6C,0x80,0x9D,0x86,0x19,0x4B,0x16,0xD3,0x17,0xAB,0x0E,0x7F,0xE8,0x5F,0xC9,0xB5,0xCC,0x9B,0x96,0xE6,0xAB,0xB6,0x7B,0x11,0x5B,0xC8,0x01,0xD7,0x16,0x50,0xD3,0xF8,0xB4,0xF5,0xCB,0xC2,0xC4,0x70,0xCD,0x84,0x50,0xD0,0x7F,0xA9,0xC3,0x8F,0xE1,0x6B,0x54,0xF4,0x32,0xB8,0x6E,0xCD,0xD2,0xCF,0x78,0x98,0x69,0x7F
            };

            /* Load public key. Modulus(N), exponent (E) */
            string Nstring = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < N.Length; i++) {
                Nstring += N[i].ToString("X2");
            }
            string Estring = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < E.Length; i++) {
                Estring += E[i].ToString("X2");
            }
            RsaKeyParameters key = new RsaKeyParameters(false, new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(Nstring, 16), new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(Estring, 16));
            PssSigner pss = new PssSigner(new RsaEngine(), new Sha256Digest(), 32, 0xBC);
            pss.Init(false, key);

            /* Verify response */
            pss.BlockUpdate(challenge, 0, challenge.Length);
            if(pss.VerifySignature(responseGiven) == false) {
                Console.WriteLine("VerifySignature failed");
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("Verification success of given response");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps someone can identify the problem from the information posted. Otherwise you should post a complete C and C# code including test data and keys so that a reproduction of the problem is possible via copy/paste, see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You appear to be using a 1024 bit RSA key, so the signature should also be 1024 bits, i.e. 128 bytes.

Comment: Oops, made a mistake in my post; I meant 8-bit arrays, not 8 byte arrays.. Corrected, and I've added a challenge and response array, these values go with the given E and N. The signature is indeed 128 bytes. I'm working on a minimal example, but that'll take some time (shifting priorities... :( )

Comment: Just added a minimal C++/mbedtls (working) and C#/BouncyCastle (problem) codelisting. Both using the same dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C/C++ code expects the hash of the message when verifying and therefore does not hash before verifying. The C# code, on the other hand, expects the message itself when verifying and performs the hashing before verifying  itself.

Therefore, if the hash of the message is passed to the C# code instead of the message, a double hashed message is verified with the signature for a single hashed message, which fails.

The problem can be solved if no hashing is performed in the C# code analog to the C/C++ code before verification. For this, e.g. under .NET Core the verification can be performed with [`RSACng#VerifyHash()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacng.verifyhash?view=netcore-3.1), which in contrast to [`RSACng#VerifyData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.verifydata?view=netcore-3.1) expects the hash of the message analogous to the C/C++ code.

A possible implementation is:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
...
/* Key */
byte[] E = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 };
byte[] N = new byte[] { 0xC2, 0x7E, 0xC0, 0xCD, 0x1B, 0xEA, 0xE1, 0x2E, 0x5F, 0x15, 0xE3, 0x9A, 0xA3, 0x5C, 0xF2, 0x0A, 0xB5, 0xAE, 0x7F, 0x22, 0xE0, 0x8A, 0xA8, 0xA7, 0x44, 0x8E, 0xDD, 0x1F, 0x3C, 0xDD, 0xDA, 0xE5, 0xBB, 0x23, 0x8F, 0xF2, 0xED, 0xFA, 0xDF, 0xC4, 0x95, 0x72, 0x67, 0x00, 0x49, 0xCF, 0xCD, 0xE7, 0x35, 0x56, 0x49, 0xE7, 0x16, 0xCC, 0x5A, 0x9A, 0x37, 0xFA, 0x0C, 0x6B, 0x79, 0xA5, 0x5B, 0x5A, 0x4C, 0x1F, 0x48, 0xE7, 0x62, 0x59, 0xFD, 0x60, 0x4A, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xB6, 0x62, 0xD2, 0xEB, 0x41, 0xF3, 0xB1, 0xDA, 0x2F, 0x61, 0x55, 0x68, 0xD1, 0x77, 0x7C, 0x16, 0xCA, 0x62, 0x2F, 0xF9, 0x6D, 0x03, 0xED, 0xCF, 0x89, 0x9D, 0x1E, 0x5B, 0xA8, 0x4D, 0x90, 0xDF, 0x80, 0x1B, 0x75, 0xE0, 0x6D, 0xAA, 0x0D, 0x8A, 0xCC, 0xA1, 0x5B, 0xE5, 0xD8, 0xA0, 0x97, 0xFF, 0x75, 0x4B, 0xDA, 0x39, 0x7D };

/* Challenge */
byte[] challenge = new byte[] {
    0x1E,0x36,0x44,0x82,0x2A,0x60,0x79,0xDE,0x7D,0x49,0x92,0xAA,0x5E,0x25,0xB5,0x80,0x6D,0x95,0x7E,0xE9,0x3A,0x30,0x9B,0x7F,0x82,0x4B,0xB0,0x26,0x3D,0x00,0x0C,0x2E
};

/* Response */
byte[] responseGiven = new byte[]{
    0xA7,0x64,0x07,0xD0,0x06,0x35,0x0E,0x3F,0x6C,0xFB,0xA1,0xB8,0xDC,0xC5,0x68,0x97,0x65,0xD5,0x7A,0x74,0xFC,0x96,0x01,0x53,0xE0,0x16,0xBC,0xCA,0x59,0x40,0x37,0xC8,0xC9,0x89,0xC2,0x84,0x2A,0xC6,0x51,0xCD,0xDA,0x29,0x65,0xBF,0x39,0x68,0x1E,0x3A,0x0E,0x4E,0x81,0x2E,0xBC,0x08,0x41,0x6A,0xC8,0x95,0xD1,0x43,0x35,0x7C,0x14,0xF6,0x2D,0xE8,0xDA,0x94,0x6C,0x80,0x9D,0x86,0x19,0x4B,0x16,0xD3,0x17,0xAB,0x0E,0x7F,0xE8,0x5F,0xC9,0xB5,0xCC,0x9B,0x96,0xE6,0xAB,0xB6,0x7B,0x11,0x5B,0xC8,0x01,0xD7,0x16,0x50,0xD3,0xF8,0xB4,0xF5,0xCB,0xC2,0xC4,0x70,0xCD,0x84,0x50,0xD0,0x7F,0xA9,0xC3,0x8F,0xE1,0x6B,0x54,0xF4,0x32,0xB8,0x6E,0xCD,0xD2,0xCF,0x78,0x98,0x69,0x7F
};

/* Load public key. Modulus(N), exponent (E) */
string Nstring = "";
for (int i = 0; i < N.Length; i++)
{
    Nstring += N[i].ToString("X2");
}
string Estring = "";
for (int i = 0; i < E.Length; i++)
{
    Estring += E[i].ToString("X2");
}
RsaKeyParameters key = new RsaKeyParameters(false, new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(Nstring, 16), new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(Estring, 16));

/*
PssSigner pss = new PssSigner(new RsaEngine(), new Sha256Digest(), 32, 0xBC);
pss.Init(false, key);

// Verify response
pss.BlockUpdate(challenge, 0, challenge.Length);
if (pss.VerifySignature(responseGiven) == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("VerifySignature failed");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Verification success of given response");
}

Console.ReadKey();
*/

RSA rsa = new RSACng();
RSAParameters rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaKeyParameters)key);
rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
bool verified = rsa.VerifyHash(challenge, responseGiven, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
Console.WriteLine("Verified: " + verified); // Verified: True

Console.ReadKey();
```

With this code the verification is successful.

Alternatively, in the original C# code, the message itself can be passed instead of the hash.

Comment: Yes, this works! Looks totally obviously now, not sure how I've missed this.. Got lost in the crypto api's I quess :) Anyways, thanks a lot!